# How to set up UIPickerView values using info procured from viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I want to set the initial values for a UIPickerView based on the picker functions:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {//return number}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {//return String}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {//return number}
```

I have left the function in generic form, because their exact code isn't important to the question. The general question/problem that I have is that the values in the functions are supposed to be based on information pulled from a DB. I have a function set up to be called in the `viewDidLoad()` that pulls the information. My question is that, basically, will the function in the `viewDidLoad()` be called (and thus have grabbed the information) before the the `pickerView` functions are called? I need to know if the `viewDidLoad()` query can pull the information to be used by the `pickerView` functions, before the `pickerView` functions run. If it happens afterward, the functions will not have the data they need. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the database query is complete, simply reload the picker:

```
pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

From the documentation:

> Calling this method causes the picker view to query the delegate for
>   new data for all components.